# Laravel Elixir BrowserSync doesn't show page

Tags: php, laravel, npm, browser-sync, laravel-elixir

After watching the newest episode on [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com) (https://laracasts.com/series/painless-builds-with-laravel-elixir/episodes/13) I decided to try out BrowserSync for Laravel Elixir.

To begin with I did the usual things for setting up a laravel project:

```
laravel new test
cd test
npm install
```

Then I tried to visit the BrowserSync UI at localhost:3001 but when I went to localhost:3000 where the actual site should be it just kept on loading and never showed the site itself.

gulp watch output:

```
[16:49:11] Using gulpfile ~/Sites/test/gulpfile.js
[16:49:11] Starting 'watch'...
[16:49:11] Finished 'watch' after 14 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://homestead.app
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------
 Local: http://localhost:3000
 ----------------------------
    UI: http://localhost:3001
 ----------------------------
[BS] Watching files...
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserSync({ online: false });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really great screen.
So i had same problem, i just run my server because in defaut setting elixir set proxy with "http://homestead.app"

So you can lunch your homestead with configuration,
or just run `php artisan` with this configuration in your gulpfile

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.browserSync({
         online: false,
         proxy : 'localhost:8000'
   });
});
```